# Finding all the rational points of the curve $x^2 -2y^2 =1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, parametrization

This question was left as an exercise in my class of number theory and I want to verify my solution.

> Question: Let $C$ be a curve given by $x^2 -2 y^2=1$. Find all the rational points on $C$.

Attempt: $( 1,0 )$ is a solution and let m be the slope of the line passing through $(1,0)$ . Now the equation of the line is $y-0 = t(x-1)$ (say $L$). So, $x= 1+y/t$.

As, the curve is an hyperbola, so this line say L will intersect the curve at least $1$ more time.

Putting $x= y/t+1$ in $x^2 -2y^2 =1 $, I get y = $\frac {2t } { 2 t^2 -1} $ and $x=  + \frac{ 2t^2 +1} {2t^2-1} , - \frac{ 2t^2 +1} {2t^2-1}$. So, these are the rational points of the curve along with $(1,0)$.

Is my solution fine?

Comment: Do your $x,y$ satisfy $x^2-2y^2=1$ ?

Comment: Your task is special case of Pell's equation.

Comment: If $y=\frac{2t}{2t^2-1}$ and $x = \frac{y}{t} + 1$, I'd think that would mean $x = \frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}$.  So for example, $t=1$ gives $(3, 2)$ which does satisfy the equation.

Comment: @reuns Yes they do. Do you have any additional comments that might help me?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, your value of x is right. I have made an edit to post. Now , my values of x satisfies the equation. Do you have any comments now?

Comment: @Bakugany It isn't Pell, because OP specifically is looking for the *rational* points on that curve. I would agree to call it Pell only if the values of $x,y$ were restricted to integers. [The rational solutions are easier to find formulas for.]

Comment: Now your rational parametrization is ok but your explanation of how you found it is extremely unclear. Also you want to show that $x,y$ are rational iff $t$ is rational.

Comment: @reuns I have proved that if t is rational then x, y are always rational . Why should I prove the converse? Still I tried to prove the converse and I showed that t is rational if both $\sqrt \frac {x+1} { 2(1-x)}$ and $ \sqrt{ 1+2y^2}$ are rational.

Comment: Setting $t=s^2$, $\frac{2s^4+1}{2s^4-1},\frac{2s^2}{2s^4-1}$ is not a rational parametrization of the curve because some rational points need $s$ irrational to be reached. Consider $1/y,x/y$ to show that $t$ must be rational for $x,y$ to be rational.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi Since my answer is not upvoted,  it must not have been useful to you. Since it is not accepted, you are not satisfied with it and you are still waiting for a better answer. Are these your intension? I am losing interest to answer other questions of yours even with bounties.

Comment: @ApassJack I am not doing well physically. Your answer is great. Thats why I awarded bounty to you. I will be back as soon as I can.

Comment: @3ibfwcbi Sorry to hear you are not well.  Hope you will be better soon. The bounty I got confused me even more. In almost all cases, whenever I got a bounty, my answer is upvoted and accepted. I might be oversensitive, but I am afraid I am not able to understand why my answer is not accepted.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Your answer has a gap as mentioned in the comment of reuns that some rational points will need s irrational to be reached. I don't think your answer tells us about those rational points?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi All rational points are represented by my answer. More explicitly, if $(x,y)$ is a rations point other than $(1,0)$, then $(x,y)=(\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$, where $t=\frac y{x-1}$. Please check. The comment of reuns does not affect my answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is basically OK. However, there are several places that could be improved.

#### A detailed solution.

If $x=1$, then $y=0$.

Suppose $(x,y)$ is a rational solution $(x,y)$ with $x\not=1$. Let the slope of the line through $(1,0)$ and $(x,y)$ be $t=\frac{y-0}{x-1}=\frac y{x-1}$, which must be a rational number.

$t=\frac y{x-1}$ implies $y=t(x-1)$. Putting $y=t(x-1)$ in $x^2-2y^2 =1$, we get $$(x-1)((2t^2-1)x-(2t^2+1))=0.$$ Since $x\not=1$, we get $x=\frac{ 2t^2 +1} {2t^2-1}$ and then y = $\frac {2t } { 2 t^2 -1} $.

Note that when $t$ is a rational number, $2t^2-1\not=0$ and both $\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}$ and $\frac{2t}{2t^2-1}$ are rational numbers.

So, all rational points are $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$.

#### Wait, don't we also have $(-\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$?

Yes, $(-\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$ are also rational points on $C$. However, they do not provide any point that is not $(1,0)$ or $(\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for some rational $t$. This fact is clear since the meticulous solution process above must have found all rational points on $C$.

It turns out that there are many parametrized solutions.

Besides the one given by $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$, all rational points on $C$ can also be $(-1,0)$ and $(-\frac{2t^2+1}{2t^2-1}, \frac{2t}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$, where $t$ can be understood as the negative of the slope of the line through $(-1,0)$ and $(x,y)$.

For anther example, consider $(3,2)$ on $C$. Let $t$ be the slope of the line through $(3,2)$ and $(x,y)$. We can find that all rational points on $C$ are $(3,\pm2)$ and $(\frac{6t^2-8t+3}{2t^2-1}, \frac{-4t^2+6t-2}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$.

More generally, suppose $(a,b)$ is a rational point on $C$. Then all rational points on $C$ are $(a, \pm b)$ and $(\frac{a(2t^2+1)-4bt}{2t^2-1}, \frac{-b(2t^2+1)+2at}{2t^2-1})$ for all rational $t$.

Comment: I use $y=t(x-1)$ instead of $x=1+y/t$ so as to allow $t=0$ explicitly.